# execve and read loop

Tags: c, pipe, execve

I'm working on a shell reproduction which is a school project. And, like good shells, i need to reproduce the pipe | feature.
I'm coding a prototype of implementation of a binary execution like /usr/bin/python.
I worked on fork(), dup2(), pipe() and execve() but i have difficulty in read stdout piped of python.

Here what i want for my demo-program :
./a.out [Path to a bin] [argv] [...]

Here is my mental algo :
1. I create a pipe
2. I fork
3. In my child i prepare a new argv for execv
4. I dup2 stdout in my write-side pipe
5. I execv with path, argument and envp
6. In my parent, i read all content from the read-side and print it for verification, in loop while my child is alive.

Here is my code to try to do that :

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <libgen.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>

void    ft_putstr(char *str) { write(1, str, strlen(str)); }

char        **l_strs_nuller(char **tab, unsigned int size)
{
    char            **new;
    unsigned int    i;

    i = 0;
    if (!tab)
        return (NULL);
    if (!(new = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*) * (size + 1))))
        return (NULL);
    while (i < size)
    {
        new[i] = strdup(tab[i]);
        i++;
    }
    new[i] = NULL;
    return (new);
}

int     main(int argc, char **argv, char **envp)
{
    char    **arg;
    pid_t   child;
    int     child_stat;
    int     pipe1[2];
    char    buf[500];

    pipe(pipe1);
    if ((child = fork()) == 0)
    {
        dup2(pipe1[1], 1); // Redirect all stdout in pipe1 write-side
        arg = l_strs_nuller(argv + 1, argc - 1); //argv + 1 to avoid a.out
        free(arg[0]); // Removing first "/usr/bin" things to put basename in the first block.
        arg[0] = strdup(basename(argv[1])); // Place file name part in the first case;
        execve(argv[1], arg, envp);
        exit(0);
    }
    else
    {
        while (waitpid(child, &child_stat, WNOHANG) == 0)
        {
            bzero(buf, 500);
            read(pipe1[0], buf, sizeof(buf));
            ft_putstr(buf);
        }
    }
    return (0);
}
```

Here is my problem :
My parent process is stuck in read() when my child is terminated.

I wanted to know if i'm in the good direction and some tips to know what i'm missing.

Thank you for reading me,
Lobbyra,

Comment: Note that `ft_putstr(buf);` can fail as a long `buf` does not certainly have a null character in it.

Answer (score 0):

you have to close `pipe1[1]` in the parent process. Else the pipe is kept open and `read()` does not see the EOF.

Usually you should close `pipe1[0]` in the child process too to avoid similar effects there.

Comment: Thanks for your replay. I don't understand why closing a side of the pipe which is not used in the process. i think i have to read more on this way.